# Unity3d Move 2D Sprite relative to mouse position

Tags: unity-game-engine, position, 2d, mouse

if I move my sprite with the mouse, the sprite is always exactly under the cursor.

At the moment my code looks like that:

```js
    public GameObject player;
    private float distance = 1;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            Vector3 mousePos = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, distance);
            Vector3 playerPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos);
            player.transform.position = playerPos;
        }
    }
```

but i want to move the sprite, no matter where my mouse courser is on the background. so if i click and hold next to the sprite and move my mouse to the right, i want that my sprite move the same way in same direction.

[Example Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSLoN.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you should use a relative movement, that is, the amount that the mouse moved from its current position when the mouse button was clicked, as if that was the origin.

So, you should take note of the current mouse position when the user pressed the mouse button.

Here is one solution that does what I describe:

```
// by Vander 'imerso' Nunes to StackOverflow answer

﻿using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MouseDrag : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;

    bool dragging = false;
    Vector3 mouseStartPos;
    Vector3 playerStartPos;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            dragging = true;
            mouseStartPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, 0));
            playerStartPos = player.transform.position;
        }
        else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            dragging = false;
        }

        if (dragging)
        {
            Vector3 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, 0));
            Vector3 move = mousePos - mouseStartPos;
            player.transform.position = playerStartPos + move;
        }
    }
}
```

You will notice that both current player position and current mouse position are noted when the button is initially pressed. So, they act as if they were the origin. The player is only moved by the distance that the mouse moves from its initial position when its button was pressed.

Comment: Wow thank you, works perfectly. I struggled so many hours with this problem

Comment: Glad to help. I see you are new here, so maybe you don't know, but you are supposed to accept the answer then. Thanks.